# @ngrxStore createSelector - Can I invoke createSelector manually? is this bad?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

Say I have a selector

```
let getCount = createSelector(countState, (count) => {count ? count : 0 });

let myChecks: Observable<{
checkThis: boolean,
checkThat: boolean,
count: string}>


this.myChecks = this.store.select(state => {
  ... somelogic

    return {
       checkThis = somelogic.checkThis;
       checkThat = somelogic.checkThat;
       count = getCount(state)
    }
  });
```

Considering I dont have selectors for everything, is above example bad? Can I just say getCount(state) inside the select instead of directly using it in select?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use selectors because they are memoized.

> When using the createSelector and createFeatureSelectorfunctions
>   @ngrx/store keeps track of the latest arguments in which your selector
>   function was invoked. Because selectors are pure functions, the last
>   result can be returned when the arguments match without reinvoking
>   your selector function. This can provide performance benefits,
>   particularly with selectors that perform expensive computation. This
>   practice is known as memoization.

[NgRX Docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md)